# Do customized bit.ly links ever expire?

Tags: url-shortening, bit.ly, customization

I'm about to send out "save the date" announcements for my wedding soon, and wanted to include a link to a our wedding page hosted on a popular planning site, theknot.com. The link options they gave us stink, so I setup a custom bit.ly URL, but I couldn't find any information about if (or when) the customized URL's expire (I know the standard shortened URL's don't expire).

Do they expire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. They don't expire.

> #### [Can I delete a bit.ly link?](http://bit.ly/pages/help#i_1_2)
>
> We believe that being a legitimate shortening service means offering permanent URLs. Our users can feel confident that the bit.ly links they create don't unexpectedly disappear or expire.

If you're worried that might not extend to custom links:

> No, all bit.ly links and custom names [are permanent by design](http://bit.ly/pages/help#i_5_4)

Comment: Great, thanks! I missed that bit about custom names.